# USB ReadFile() works only after the third time?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, usb, hid

I am developing a custom USB HID device with both IN and OUT interrupt endpoints of 64 bytes length each. There are 2 reports (one with report ID 1 and other with report ID 2) with report count of 63 bytes each. When the PC app developed in VC++ sends a 64 byte buffer using WriteFile(), I receive the entire buffer properly at the device on the OUT interrupt endpoint. But when I send a 64 byte buffer from the device to the PC on the IN endpoint, the ReadFile() returns with a value of 4 (timeout). This happens only 2 times when the device is plugged in. After that everything works fine and the PC reads the 64 bytes sent by the device properly.

I am using USBlyzer tool to sniff the USB bus traffic. That software shows that for the first two times the device sends a 64 byte buffer on the interrupt IN endpoint, but it too is not able to show the data in it. And the 3rd time onwards, everything works magically, both PC application and USBlyzer receive and display the 64 bytes buffer contents on the screen.

I am not sure where exactly the problem lies, is it on the PC side code or in the device firmware? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait until the data are aviable. How big is your timeout?

Comment: Try obtaining a file open handle for the file first. Also, are you doing this immediately you insert the USB?

Comment: The problem is solved. From the firmware I was calling the Prepare RxBuffer function (from STM32 library) with a wrong parameter value for the number of bytes. My mistake was I was entering the number of bytes which I expect from the PC, it should have been the max number of bytes the endpoint can transfer (in my case 64).